# Unexpected 0 output shape after converting pt model to other format via pytorch export script

Tags: android, pytorch, yolov5

I am creating an Android app and use yolov5 segmentation model to segment images from camera.

But inference doesn't work correctly and shows output shape as 0 dimensional tensor.

The reason of problem as i found is wrong converting weights from pt format to other format(i needed ptl)

I am using export.py script from yolov5 repository.
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

Conversion goes normal but as a result i am getting 0 output shape model as you can see on the screen below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Y6g.jpg)

I have tried several models and several weights files and several formats, the results always are the same: 0 output shape.

So the question is why it's happening?

Environment:
torch 2.0.1

I have tried several models like yolov3s,yolov5s, yolov5s_seg and several weights files and several formats, the results always are the same: 0 output shape.

I am expecting to see :

```
 PyTorch: starting from yolov5s_seg.pt with output shape (25200,85) (14.9 MB)
```

In general i am expecting to see normal outputshape, which is not (0,)